# How do I refer to an element in a nested list within a for-loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, coordinates, nested-lists

I have a nested list of coordinates `[[x1, y1],[x2, y2],[x3,y3]...]`.

I want to use a `for-loop` in order to determine the distance in the x-direction between two consecutive points. I want to do the same thing for the y-direction later. This is my attempt so far:

```
p1=[X1, Y1]
p2=[X2, Y2]
p3=[X3, Y3]
p4=[X4, Y4]
p5=[X5, Y5]
coordiantes = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5]
    
for i in coordinates:
            p1_x = i[0]
            p2_x = i[0]+1
            p1_y = i[1]
            p2_y = i[1]+1
            distance_x = p2_x - p1_x
```

Apparently, `i[0]+1` doesn't give you the subsequent x-value in the next list but adds `1` to the first x-value.

My question is how do I refer to the subsequent x-value in my nested list? So, if `i` referred to `p1`, I also want to get `p2` in that loop.

I also tried adding another variable `j` and assigning it `j = i + 1` so that I can refer to the subsequent x-value by using j[0]. However, I get the error that one cannot concatenate list to int.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i in coordinates` is a for-each loop. You don't have access to the current index, `i` is directly the list child.

You should loop using `range` or `enumerate` if you want to access the adjacent item by incrementing current index. For example,

```
for ind in range(len(coordinates)-1):
            p1_x = coordinates[ind][0]
            p2_x = coordinates[ind+1][0]
            p1_y = coordinates[ind][1]
            p2_y = coordinates[ind+1][1]
            distance_x = p2_x - p1_x
```

The range limit is len-1 because we don't want to process the last element (ind+1 would be out of bounds).

Answer (score 0):

```
for i, n in enumerate(coord):
    try:
        print(coord[i]
        print(coord[i+1])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

try/except part for indexerror. except that, gives an error in last digit. or also you could use :

```
for i, n in enumerate(coord):
    if i == len(coord)-1:
        pass
    else:
        print(coord[i])
        print(coord[i+1])
```

also, for enumerate basically you could use `range(len(coord))` and without try/except and if part `range(len(coord)-1)` gives what you want to